# Need to update many columns with unique values which matches with respective unique values condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update 2 columns in the database of around 10,000 rows with unique values depending on the unique value of the column that is known to me.

Column values I have:

```
tag_name
xxxxx
yyyyy
zzzzz
```

Column values I need to update

```
tag_name     Hierarchical Name
xxxx2        xxxx2
yyyy2        yyyy2
zzzz2        zzzz2
```

where tag_name = xxxxx the values of tag_name and hierarchical_name should change to xxxx2

where tag_name = yyyyy the values of tag_name and hierarchical_name should change to yyyy2

where tag_name = zzzzz the values of tag_name and hierarchical_name should change to zzzz2

Can anyone help me to build a SQL query for this? I am new to this.

Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

This query i am running on 2014 sql server

```
UPDATE [PSRTMSCADA].[dbo].[gobject]
SET tag_name= 'New_Crate 2',
Hierarchical_Name = 'New_Crate 2'
WHERE tag_name = 'Crate 1'

SET tag_name = 'New_Monitor2',
Hierarchical_Name = 'New_Monitor2'
Where tag_name = 'Monitor'

        I am expecting to know how easily i can do this..
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
UPDATE [PSRTMSCADA].[dbo].[gobject]
SET Hierarchical_Name= case when tag_name = 'Crate 1' then 
                      'New_Crate 2'
                   when tag_name = 'Monitor' then 'New_Monitor2'
                  else Hierarchical_Name end,
tag_name = case when tag_name = 'Crate 1' then 
                      'New_Crate 2'
                   when tag_name = 'Monitor' then 'New_Monitor2' 
                   else tag_name end
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code describes is:

```
UPDATE [PSRTMSCADA].[dbo].[gobject]
    SET tag_name= (CASE WHEN tag_name = 'Crate 1' THEN 'New_Crate 2'
                        WHEN tag_name = 'Monitor' THEN 'New_Monitor2'
                   END),
        Hierarchical_Name = (CASE WHEN tag_name = 'Crate 1' THEN 'New_Crate 2'
                                  WHEN tag_name = 'Monitor' THEN 'New_Monitor2'
                             END)
    WHERE tag_name IN ('Crate 1', 'Monitor');
```

It can be tricky to maintain such code, though.  So, I prefer to list the values and use `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE g
    SET tag_name = new_tag_name,
        Hierarchical_Name = new_hierarchical_name
    FROM gobject g JOIN
         (VALUES ('Crate 1', 'New_Crate 2', 'New_Crate 2'),
                 ('Monitor', 'New_Monitor2', 'New_Monitor2')
         ) v(tag_name, new_tag_name, new_hierarchical_name)
         ON g.tag_name = v.tag_name;
```

Comment: Dear Gordon,  Thanks... I am unable to understand what is meant by g and v that u have used in  your answered query...  g is [PSRTMSCADA].[dbo].[gobject] then what is v... i am newbie in SQL... can u please help

Comment: @syedmuffassir . . . These are table aliases.  They are an important part of the language.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I used   "FROM [PSRTMSCADA].[dbo].[gobject] g JOIN" and it worked... i read about aliases and as u guided me ... i read about aliases and found it helpful and now i got the basic knowledge..... I am an industrial automation engineer and needed to do bulk change of tags... so i asked this query